# All of my favourites look the same!

Tags: support

If you use the favourites function and have accumulated a number of favourites, I am sure that, over time, you will look back and think, "Why on earth did I favourite that question?" This is obviously because there is no functionality to add a comment.

Apart from either having a piece of paper, or a textpad document that you use to cross reference the URLs/question titles with notes (tedious and liable to get lost or confused), how can I keep track of why I clicked on the favourite star?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Favorites improvements - search, categorize, personal tags, add note, favorite answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75944/favorites-improvements-search-categorize-personal-tags-add-note-favorite-a), you might find that [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75944/favorites-improvements-search-categorize-personal-tags-add-note-favorite-a#answer-251234) could help you tremendously.

ᔕᖺᘎᕊ has written a very useful stack app. I have been using it for over a month now, and have found it invaluable, and tbh, I don't know how I functioned before installing it.

The stack app is available here: [Favourites Enhancer: Tag favourites and add personal notes](https://stackapps.com/questions/6215/favourites-enhancer-tag-favourites-and-add-personal-notes)

[image: Gif]

You will need to install [Tampermonkey](https://tampermonkey.net) (or Greasemonkey), and I've tested it on Opera and Firefox, and it works fine on both.